# Hidden Field Value not finding value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, hiddenfield

I have an hiddenfield field in my gridview but the code behind cant get its value maybe someone could find the problem.
HTML:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TweetID" Visible="false">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HiddenField ID="TweetID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("TweetID") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

.cs:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
    HiddenField tid = GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("TweetID") as HiddenField;
    //Response.Write(tid.Value);
    TweetHelper.RemoveTweet( Convert.ToInt32(tid.Value), 1);
}
```

by the way the response writes nothing.

Comment: I tested your code and it works OK. I get the HiddenField and its value in code-behind. What do you mean by "the response writes nothing"? Is the databound control empty after postback? Is the HiddenField value empty?

Comment: I dont know it did not work for me i tested it on another gridview and it worked maybe my gridview has a problem somewhere but i fixed it now thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code above what you are doing is overkill.

Either make `TweetID` a Gridview.DataKey.

Or if that's not an option, convert your `Delete` button to a template field and add `TweetID` as a `CommandArgument` to the `Delete` button.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine.However another way to find the control is

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
HiddenField hdn = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("TweetID");
string value = hdn.Value;
```

or simply

```
var tweetid = ((HiddenField)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TweetID")).Value;
```